# How do I write these classes into one when declaring them in CSS?

Tags: css, class, concatenation, html

This is the code I'm trying to concatenate (may have misinterpreted that word), how do I make them both do the same thing without declaring another class with the same attributes?

```
.games span {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.console span {
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;

}
```

Comment: Remember to accept an answer where appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You use a comma to separate the two selections:

```
.games span, .console span {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

So the comma can be better interpreted to us humans as **and**

Answer (score 0):

```
.games span, .console span{
  //your css
}
```